# Problem with my custom dialog which is having dynamic data

Tags: android

I have a usecase like repeatedly calling the same dialog box with different values. I am using the same dialog creating code for that. First time the sent data is populated to dialog box. but next time the dialog box not getting rebuilt with different values when i call the same for next time.

Code is here

```
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.orderdialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Selected Item");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            System.out.println(selected);  // here i am sending different values eachtime. But not updating in dialog.

            TextView selectedItem = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            selectedItem.setText(selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android alert builder to show dynamic data:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("your title name")
    .setMessage("here you can write your dynamic data as string or integer")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(/* don't remember the signature by heart... */) { 
            // continue with delete
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(/* don't remember the signature by heart... */) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
     .show();
```

Comment: Hey Sitanshu Joshi, Thank you for the reply. But here i need to use CustomDialog box. I need to call the same dialog box for multiple times. Each time with different data. Your code will not work for my usecase. Any way thanx

Comment: @ Rajashekhar Reddy you can also put this in publi static method. call the method and pass the parameter of your data while calling it. i think this would be better for you.

Comment: @Joshi : Actually in my usecase if i select one item, then in custom dialog respective item, quantity and price should be displayed. if i select qty from spinner view in dialog, the price should be updated. For this i need to use Custom dialog box. If you have any solution, plz tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling 
showDialog(id);
and creating dialog in oncreatDialog function

create the dialog and show it in you on click function itself:

like this:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("State");
                builder.setItems(m_arrStateNames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_nSelStateIdx = which;
                        showState();

                        dialog.dismiss();
                   }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
```